# /proc in Kernel Modules

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

Currently I am learning Kernel Module Programming reading "https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf" ,and in that book there is a chapter titled as "/proc File System", I have learnt how modules are used as device drivers, but I have not been able to understand the importance of creating "/proc/file_name" by an kernel module. I know that in /proc directory kernel maintains info about processes.
I need to understand the importance of creating "/proc/file_name" by an kernel module.

Answer (score 3):

The beginning of chapter 5.1 says this about the `/proc` filesystem:

> Originally designed to allow easy access to information about processes (hence the name), it is now used by every bit of the kernel which has something interesting to report, [...]

You don't *have* to create a file in the `/proc` filesystem, but if you want or need to have an easy way to report statistics or other information about the state of your module, the `/proc` filesystem is one way to do it. Because of the way the `/proc` filesystem was developed, it can be a bit disorganized. Instead of creating several things at the root of the `/proc` filesystem, you might want to create a sub-directory for your module at e.g. `/proc/driver`, to minimize the chance of conflicts with the main kernel, other third-party modules or future development.

Note that about the time that book was being written, the `/sys` filesystem was also introduced to be a more systematically arranged place (and so more friendly for integrating user-space tools) for any tunable settings your kernel module might have. Unfortunately, the chapter 6 that was supposed to be about it is just a `TODO: Write a chapter about sysfs` placeholder in that PDF.

(Historical note: before the `/sys` filesystem existed, the `/proc` filesystem was used as a place for run-time tweakable settings, usually identifiable as writeable files. Some of them might still not have been completely migrated to the `/sys` filesystem, or even not going to migrate at all to maintain backward compatibility. But for any modern development, it would be better to put any tunables in `/sys` instead of `/proc`.)

In modern kernels, there is also the `debugfs`, that can be mounted to `/sys/kernel/debug`, that could be a good place if your kernel module needs a way to output some debugging information. It might be a good place for outputting more detailed/sensitive debug information, as `debugfs` is designed for system administrator access only. It is also completely optional: in production systems the `debugfs` can be simply left unmounted unless there is a need for in-depth troubleshooting.

So, in a nutshell: if your module needs to provide a way to tune some settings at run-time, the `/sys` filesystem is a good place for them. For debugging information in modern kernels, use the `debugfs`. For statistics and similar stuff that can be seen by non-root users, `/proc` can be used.

Comment: you need to say that if my module wants to show some stats , just like kernel shows in "/proc/modules" which indicates that which of the modules are currently inserted , I can do that by creating file in "/proc" file system and writing the info.